# Why doesn't the reference get added to Class Library the project even after I add it to the Class Library project

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I add this reference to the Class Library project:
[image: System.Windows.Forms]

and nothing changes in the code. I still get an error when I add the using statement:
[image: Error in Using Statement]

Then I go back to the Reference Manager and the reference is not there. :(

[image: Missing Reference that I just added]

Comment: The odds that you *actually* want to add a COM reference to the .NET 2.0 type library for winforms are zero.  Instead, edit the .csproj file and add `<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>`

Comment: @HansPassant That kind-of works, what's the difference between the two fixes?

Comment: They have nothing in common.  Nobody can guess why you're trying to do this, maybe it is fine, maybe you'll discover you've wasted a month of your life.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem